# Wordpress get_post_meta - how can I check for multiple keys?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to work out conditionals with Wordpress post meta. I've been using `get_post_meta()` to display content if user had populated the post meta, but I need to improve the rule and add some additional conditionals to it.

Basically, what I need to do is extend this condition to multiple keys. If the user typed in both `post_meta_1` and `post_meta_2` some code will run, if not then some other code will run.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
if (!((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_meta_1', TRUE))=='')) {
    // code here
} elseif {
    // code here as well
}?>
```

Here's how far my PHP logic goes:

```
if (!((get_post_meta($post->ID, array('post_meta_1', 'post_meta_2'), false))=='')) {
    // code here
} elseif {
    // code here as well
}?>
```

*EDIT*

Somehow I managed to get it to work by using this method:

```
<?php

$post_meta_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_meta_1', TRUE);
$post_meta_2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_meta_2', TRUE);

if ($post_meta_1 && $post_meta_2) : ?>

CODE HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't know why, but using an array doesn't work, it completely ignores every other value but the first one..

Comment: Well, you cannot pass an array as second parameter to the function `get_post_meta()`, it should be a **string**, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: Yep, your edit is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @bodi0 the example is not correct as `$post_meta_1` and `$post_meta_2` are never being set

Comment: Indeed, it should be `if ($approved_environment && $capacity) {...}`

Comment: yeah, sorry, that's fixed. Happy I actually managed to figure this out, thanks for helping :)

Comment: You can have many key/value pairs with the same key. For example: `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'address' /* No third arg, same as FALSE */);`. If you have added more that one explicitly with `add_post_meta` (not update), you will receive them as array of addresses. They will be separate records in database for the same post ID with the same `meta_key`.

Comment: Or save an array inside *one single post meta* and use [**`in_array()`**](http://php.net/in_array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to call `get_post_meta()` individually for each `meta_key` that you would like a value for. You ***can*** have multiple values stored under a single `meta_key` which is what the third parameter is for - `true` returns a single value, `false` an array of values for that `meta_key`. The result of `get_post_meta()` will be `=== false` if there is no value in the database, or you can just check for `empty()` as well.

```
$capacity = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_meta_1', true );
$approved_environment = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_meta_2', true );

if ( $capacity && $approved_environment ){
    // post_meta_1 AND post_meta_2 are set
}

if ( false !== $capacity && false !== $approved_environment ){
    // post_meta_1 AND post_meta_2 are not set
}

if ( false !== $capacity || false !== $approved_environment ){
    // post_meta_1 AND/OR post_meta_2 are not set
}

if ( empty( $capacity ) && empty( $approved_environment ) ){
    // post_meta_1 AND post_meta_2 are not set or are equal to "", null, or 0
}

if ( empty( $capacity ) || empty( $approved_environment ) ){
    // post_meta_1 AND/OR post_meta_2 are not set or are equal to "", null, or 0
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, and for some reason I can't get it to work using the brackets. Using `if ($post_meta_1 && $post_meta_2) : ?>` markup does work however. I used your other statements to flesh out the rules i had though, so thanks :)

Comment: I think you are confusing the meta keys and the variable names they are assigned to. In your example above you have the meta key preceded with a $, but I'm not assigning anything to that variable in my example.